# can't rewrite URL CentOS 6.9

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just changed server. The older server run CentOS 5 and my new Running CentOS 6.9.

I didn't change any rewrite rule in .htaccess file this are the rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

##security
RewriteRule ^logo/(.*)\.(php|php3|pl|cgi)$ / [L]
RewriteRule ^other/(.*)\.(php|php3|pl|cgi)$ / [L]
RewriteRule ^logs/(.*)\.(php|php3|pl|cgi)$ / [L]
##end security
##test rewrite##
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/testrewrite(/)?$ $1/testrewrite.php?mod_r=1 [L]
##end test rewrite##

RewriteRule ^login/(.*)(/)$ login.php?login=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^support/(.*)(/)$ support.php?type=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?auth_sess=(.*)$ $1.php?auth_sess=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php(/)?$ $2.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)/$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I check my httpd.conf file

> AllowOverride All

When I run this command apachectl -M | sort , this are lauded modules

```
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 asis_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 bwlimited_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 core_module (static)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http_module (static)
 include_module (shared)

 Loaded Modules:

 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
security2_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
slotmem_shm_module (shared)
socache_dbm_module (shared)
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
so_module (static)
ssl_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
suexec_module (shared)
suphp_module (shared)
unique_id_module (shared)
unixd_module (shared)
userdir_module (shared)
version_module (shared)
```

Does anyone know what maybe wrong ?

Comment: check allowoverride inside httpd.conf.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar I checked it set to AllowOverride All